# Proof that lcm$(1, \ldots, n)=O(e^n)$

Tags: asymptotics, gcd-and-lcm

I'm trying to prove that 
lcm$$(1, \ldots, n)=O(e^n)$$

I know that lcm$(1, \ldots, n)^{1/n}$ converges to $e$ so given any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists some positieve integer $n_0$ such that if $n \geq n_0$ then
$$\mathrm{lcm}(1, \ldots, n) \leq (e+\varepsilon)^n$$
but I'm not able to get the inequality just for $e$.
How can you get such inequality?

Comment: What goes in the "$\cdots$"?

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting something here, $1$ only has itself as a divisor, hence $\gcd(1,\dots)=1$ regardless.

Comment: Did you mean LCM? If so, note each prime $p\le n$ contributes a prime power factor $\le n$. By the PNT, there are asymptotically $n/\ln n=\log_ne^n$ of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you mean $\mathrm{lcm}$ instead of $\mathrm{gcd}$. In terms of the Chebyshev function
$$
{\mathop{\rm lcm}\nolimits} (1,2, \ldots ,n) = e^{\psi (n)} .
$$
By a theorem of E. Schmidt, there is a positive constant $K$, such that for infinitely many natural numbers $n$,
$$
e^{\psi (n)}  > e^{n + K\sqrt n } .
$$
Hence, ${\mathop{\rm lcm}\nolimits} (1,2, \ldots ,n)=\mathcal{O}(e^n)$ cannot hold for all sufficiently large $n$.